# Use TFS Proxy server for TFS Git Repositories

Tags: tfs

I understand that the TFS 2018 Update 1 and later versions of TFS should be able to proxy a Git Repository.

We are hosting a few Git repositories inside our on premise TFS Collection, running TFS 2018 Update 3.

We have multiple TFS Proxy servers setup in remote locations, currently servicing collections for TFVC Projects.

- Is it correct that the TFS proxy should now be able to host a GIT Cache ?
- How do we configure the proxy server to Cache on (or all ?) GIT repositories in our TFS Server.
- What URL should be configured on the client side as Git Cache server ?

There is no documentation on this on the MSDN site other than 1 example command without explanation

> TFSConfig Proxy /add /Collection:https://HelenaPetersen.tfs.visualstudio.com/PhoneSaver /inputs:GvfsProjectName=PhoneSaver;GvfsRepositoryName=AnotherRepository

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's correct. As far as I know, Git caching via the proxy is **not** supported. TFVC is supported, and [GVFS is supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2018-update1#gvfsproxy). [GVFS](https://vfsforgit.org/) is not the same thing as Git; it is a Git extension for a very specific use-case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So what you are saying is that inside TFS i am able to host  a repo using TFVC or GIT, the Proxy is able to Cache TFVC and GVFS. To setup a GVFS repo i need to download GVFS and set it up next to TFS, right ? i cannot create a GVFS repo inside our TFS environment.